# How to get a specific cell on a table by its headers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the .html() of a cell of my table throw jQuery knowing only its data-col and data-row attributes. This is the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th data-col="A">Mon</th><th data-col="B">Tue</th>
        <th data-col="C">Wen</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-row="1">Mon</th>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Somthing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-row="2">Mon</th>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Somthing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-row="3">Mon</th>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Somthing</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know how to build this jQuery selector
somthing like: `$('table>tbody>tr[data-row=2] td')` but i can't figure out

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ohenat/5/edit)***

```
function getTD(col, row){

   var rowIdx = $('[data-row='+row+']').parent('tr').index() ;
   var colIdx = $('[data-col='+col+']').index() -1;

   return $('tr:eq('+rowIdx+') td:eq('+colIdx+')').html() ; 
}

alert(   getTD('A', '2')    );
```

Or you can also do it like:

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/ohenat/7/edit)**

```
function getTD(c,r) {

  var col = {A:1, B:2, C:3}; // add more if needed

  var colLen = $.map(col, function(n, i) { return i; }).length;
  var cc =  colLen*(r-1) + col[c]; 
  return $('table').find('td').eq(cc).html();

}

alert(   getTD('B', 3)   );
```

The cleverness of the second solution could be much more fun if you used Numbers for retrieving the COL too:

```
function getTD(col,row) {     
  var ind =  (row-1)*3 + col; // 3 is the max N of Cols
  // 'ind' holds the exact index number of our desired TD from our .find() collection
  return $('table').find('td').eq( ind ).html();     
}

// getTD( COL, ROW )
alert(   getTD(2, 3)   );
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick sketch of a solution:

```
// Param table: the <table> DOM element,
// Param col: the string identifying the column,
// Param row: the string identifying the row
function(table, col, row) {
  col_number = $(table).find("tr").first().find("th[data-col=" + col + "]").index(); 
  row_number = $(table).find("th[data-row=" + row + "]").parent().index(); 
  return $(table).find("tr").eq(row_number).find("td").eq(col_number).val();
}
```

Not tested and probably buggy in a variety of ways. Nevertheless the general idea should be clear and easy to get right with the help of the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll mark cols with index, that solution could be smaller and quicker than Confusion's answer.

```
/**
 param table - DOM element of table
 param row - row index
 param col - col index
*/
function getData(table, row, col) {
    return $(table).find('tr:nth-child('+(row+1)+')').find('td:nth-child('+(col+1)+')').html();
}
```

this function will make what you need.

[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/agadin/1/edit)

Comment: Great solution. I will think on use numbers